# Why does my C program print out the same output no matter what I put for the input?

Tags: c

I'm new to C and I've been working on this homework problem for about 2 hours to no avail. I'm attempting to create a program that takes an alphabetic phone number (ie; CALLATT or 1-800-COL-LECT) and turns it into the number form (2255288 or 1-800-265-5328). No matter what I put for input, though, I always get -4197680 for my output.

```
int main(void){

    int c=0, len, a[len];   
    char n[len];

    printf("Enter phone number: \n");
    scanf("%c", n);

    len = sizeof(n) / sizeof(n[0]);

    while (len > c){
        if (n[c] == 'A' || n[c] == 'B' || n[c] == 'C'){
            a[c] = 2;       
            c++;
        }
        else if (n[c] == 'D' || n[c] == 'E' || n[c] == 'F'){
            a[c] = 3;       
            c++;
        }
        else if (n[c] == 'G' || n[c] == 'H' || n[c] == 'I'){
            a[c] = 4;       
            c++;
        }
        else if (n[c] == 'J' || n[c] == 'L' || n[c] == 'L'){
            a[c] = 5;       
            c++;
        }
        else if (n[c] == 'M' || n[c] == 'N' || n[c] == 'O'){
            a[c] = 6;       
            c++;
        }
        else if (n[c] == 'P' || n[c] == 'Q' || n[c] == 'R' || n[c] == 'S'){
            a[c] = 7;       
            c++;
        }
        else if (n[c] == 'T' || n[c] == 'U' || n[c] == 'V'){
            a[c] = 8;       
            c++;
        }
        else if (n[c] == 'W' || n[c] == 'X' || n[c] == 'Y' || n[c] == 'Z'){
            a[c] = 9;       
            c++;
        }
        else {
            a[c] = n[c];
            c++;
        }           
    }

    printf("%d\n", a);

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: and shouldn't it be `scanf("%s", &n)` ?

Comment: I see UB here. `int a, len, a[len];` --- `len` is uninitialized at the point where it's used for `a` (and `n` in the next line). Also note that this is making use of a rather poorly supported feature of C99 (though at least GCC and CLang support it just fine).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro: No. `scanf` takes a pointer to the start of the buffer, not a pointer to a pointer (no need to, since it doesn't allocate any memory by itself).

Comment: @MoreFoam: May I recommend you *always* compile with warnings enabled? That use of an uninitialized variable would've been caught if you had. Use `-Wall` if you're using GCC or CLang; check your compiler's manual for the correct switch if you're using something else.

Comment: @TimČas I haven't used C in years, and remembered about the `&` but was not sure. Thanks for the reminder

Comment: Hmm, I'm still having trouble seeing. I am assuming my problem is len? But how can I make it initialize before everything else so that I may use it to define the length of my arrays?

Or is there some way to define the length of an array later in my program (not initially)?

Comment: No, the size of arrays is determined when their definition is encountered. In your case avoid the problem by using a suitably large number. Phone numbers aren't arbitrarily long.

Comment: @MoreFoam: Yes, using dynamic allocation. I'm sure there are plenty of sources online (I'd link one, but I don't know of any, sorry). Note that dynamic allocation makes them *technically* not arrays in C nomenclature; most people still call them arrays though.

Comment: @MoreFoam: See JensGustedt's comment above. Since you're dealing with phone numbers, you could just use an array that is "long enough"; one of the few cases where statically-sized arrays in C work just fine for user input (assuming you input it safely to avoid buffer overflows).

Comment: a is an array.  When you write `printf("%d\n", a)`, the `a` decays to a pointer and is passed to the printf function as the address of the first element in a.  This is not what you want.  It looks like you want to declare a as a char[], assign `a[c] = '8'` (with single quotes) and use `%s` as a format specifier.  Don't forget to null terminate.

Comment: Not one person is going to recommend stepping through the program in the debugger to see why the actual behavior is not matching the expected behavior?

Comment: @PeteBaughman no need to as the error is obvious on the first line of main

Comment: It's more of a "Teach a man to fish" thing.  Using a debugger will prevent the need for a future -3 vote stackoverflow question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: Revised. There were many comments pointing out problems, here is my answer which works with a reasonable length phone number. It skips any non-dialing characters, such as `'-'` which is not part of a phone number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){
    int k, d, e, len;
    char dial[20], entry[20] = {0};
    printf("Enter phone number: ");
    fgets(entry, 19, stdin);
    len = strlen(entry);
    d = 0;                                 // dial string index of output
    for (e=0; e<len; e++) {                // entry string index of input
        k = entry[e];
        switch (toupper(k)) {
            case 'A': case 'B': case 'C':           dial[d++] = '2'; break;
            case 'D': case 'E': case 'F':           dial[d++] = '3'; break;
            case 'G': case 'H': case 'I':           dial[d++] = '4'; break;
            case 'J': case 'K': case 'L':           dial[d++] = '5'; break;
            case 'M': case 'N': case 'O':           dial[d++] = '6'; break;
            case 'P': case 'Q': case 'R': case 'S': dial[d++] = '7'; break;
            case 'T': case 'U': case 'V':           dial[d++] = '8'; break;
            case 'W': case 'X': case 'Y': case 'Z': dial[d++] = '9'; break;
            default:
                if (isdigit(k) || k=='*' || k=='#') dial[d++] = k;
        }
    }
    dial[d] = 0;          // terminate string
    printf("Dial %s\n", dial);
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! It seems like using switch instead of a while loop works a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code:

```
char buf[32];
sscanf("%31s", buf);

size_t i;

for (i = 0; i < sizeof(buf) && buf[i]; ++i)
{
switch (buf[i])
{
case 'A': case 'B': case 'C':
    buf[i] = '2'; break; // Note: character literal, not integer
case 'D': case 'E': case 'F':
   buf[i] = '3'; break;
....
}
}
printf("%s", buf);
```

If you have a Posix-compliant library, you can use dynamic allocation:

```
char *buf;
scanf("%ms", &buf); //scanf would allocate memory

for (i = 0; buf[i]; ++i)
{
.....
}

printf("%s", buf);
free(buf);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many problems in your code, it will almost need a re-write to make it work. I think you should start something small. Make sure it works before adding more functionality. I would suggest dividing the code in `main` into three sections -- reading the phone number, converting phone number and printing the converted phone number.

Here's a skeletal program that captures those three steps.

```
#define SIZE 50

void readPhoneNumber(char phoneNumber[])
{
}

void convertTextToNumber(char phoneNumber[], char dialedNumber[])
{
}

void printPhoneNumber(char phoneNumber[])
{
}

int main(void)
{
   char phoneNumber[SIZE];
   char dialedNumber[SIZE];

   readPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

   convertTextToNumber(phoneNumber, dialedNumber);

   printPhoneNumber(dialedNumber);
}
```

Now, you can start fleshing out the functions. For example, `readPhoneNumber` can be implemented as:

```
void readPhoneNumber(char phoneNumber[])
{
   printf("Enter phone number: \n");
   fgets(phoneNumber, SIZE, stdin);
}
```

`printPhoneNumber` can be implemented as:

```
void printPhoneNumber(char phoneNumber[])
{
   printf("%s\n", phoneNumber);
}
```

I'll leave you to work out the implementation of `convertTextToNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have undefined behavior, len is not initialized.

```
int c=0, len, a[len];   
char n[len];
```

Use instead a constant value instead, i bet the phone number in your country has some kind of maximum length.

---

This way to read from the keyboard is not recommended, scanf does not check for length of string so you can do a faceroll on the keyboard and your program will crash. Instead use fgets( ) to read from stdin then go through the string char by char skipping the included `\n`

```
printf("Enter phone number: \n");
scanf("%c", n);
```

---

This makes no sense, you calculate the sizeof n i.e. of the integer that holds n. If you want the length of the string use strlen( n ); btw try to use more descriptive variable names.

```
len = sizeof(n) / sizeof(n[0]);
```

---

Instead of

```
while (len > c){
```

why not use a normal for-loop ? you seem to increment c++ everywhere.

---

this here will not do what you expect it to do

```
printf("%d\n", a);
```

but you assign 'a' integers e.g.

```
a[c] = 2;
```

printf can not magically print a number of your array, instead you want to print out is a string with the numbers. the ascii value of a digit is 48 + digit. e.g. '0' is 48, by knowing this have a character buffer and add the ascii values to it. make sure it ends with \0 which is end of string. then print out the string

```
buf[c++] = 48 + digit;
...
buf[c] = '\0';   
puts( buf );
```